# Move (or "Undo") last git commit to unstaged area

Tags: git

What's the best way to move your last git commit back into the "Changes not staged" + "Untracked files" areas (with the commit in question being not-pushed / only in your local repo, effectively removing it from HEAD)?

In other words, how do you roll back a commit, but automatically apply that diff to your unstaged area?

Answer (score 418, accepted):

You can use [`git reset`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reset) to set the current branch to the preceding commit, i.e. [`HEAD^`](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitrevisions#Documentation/gitrevisions.txt-emltrevgtltngtemegemHEADv1510em)

```
git reset HEAD^
```

Adding `--soft` will keep those files in the *index*: (ready to be committed)

```
git reset --soft HEAD^
```

> `--soft`
>
> (…) This leaves all your changed files "Changes to be committed", as git status would put it.

Comment: @Dr_Zaszuś, [here we go](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Reset-Demystified) (I liked the pictures in the original post better, to be honest ;-) ).

Comment: @Dr_Zaszuś, [the original](http://web.archive.org/web/20120511055637/http://git-scm.com/2011/07/11/reset.html) courtesy The Internet Wayback Machine.

Comment: If your zsh shell returns `zsh: no matches found: HEAD^` when you run this, see: https://stackoverflow.com/q/26292192/12484

Answer (score 8):

[git-extras](https://github.com/tj/git-extras) provides a `git undo` command which is an easier to remember way of doing the same thing (along with a number of other handy extras, as the name implies).