# zsh shell does not recognize git HEAD^

Tags: git, zsh

I am using zsh shell and prezto with cygwin. When I type this git command:

```
git reset HEAD5
```

zsh returns:

```
zsh: no matches found: HEAD^
```

But when I switch to use bash shell, it works.

Why does zsh throw an error when I try to use `HEAD^`?

Comment: Found this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh/issues/449)

Answer (score 35):

The `^` character is treated as special in filename expansions in zsh, but only if the `EXTENDED_GLOB` option is set:

```
zsh% setopt noEXTENDED_GLOB
zsh% echo HEAD^
HEAD^
zsh% setopt EXTENDED_GLOB
zsh% echo HEAD^
zsh: no matches found: HEAD^
zsh%
```

Bash doesn't have this feature. (To be precise, bash does have an extended glob feature, enabled by `shopt -s extglob`, but bash's extended glob syntax doesn't treat the `^` character as special.)

With this feature enabled, `^` is a special character similar to `*` but with a different meaning. Like `*`, you can inhibit its special meaning by escaping it, either by enclosing it in single or double quotes or by preceding it with a backslash. Quoting is the simplest solution.

Rather than

```
git reset HEAD^
```

try this:

```
git reset 'HEAD^'
```

The meaning of the `^` wildcard is not relevant, since all you need to do is avoid using it, but I'll mention it anyway. According to the zsh manual, `^X` matches anything *except* the pattern `X`. For the case of `HEAD^`, nothing follows the `^` -- which means that `HEAD^` matches `HEAD` followed by anything other than nothing. That's a roundabout way of saying that `HEAD^` matches file names starting with `HEAD` and followed by some non-empty string. Given files `HEAD`, `HEAD1`, and `HEAD2`, the pattern `HEAD^` matches `HEAD1` and `HEAD2`.

Answer (score 7):

A quick workaround to avoid the `^` character is to use `git reset head~1` instead of `git reset head^`.

See [this post for the difference between the two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2221658/whats-the-difference-between-head-and-head-in-git).

Answer (score 4):

[issue 449](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/issues/449) of oh-my-zsh describes this exact behaviour and provides the solution.

The culprit is the option `extended_glob` on zsh. Presto must be setting it. So when you type `HEAD^` zsh tries to create a glob negation expression and fails with an error.

In other words, `setopt extended_glob` allows us to use `^` to negate globs.

To fix it, you can write this line on your `.zshrc`:

```
unsetopt nomatch
```

With the above line, we are saying to zsh we want that when pattern matching fails, simply use the command "as is".

Comment: Not recommended to unset `nomatch` just to avoid this error. This will have knock-on behaviour for all other shell code that the user might not want or expect. It's probably better to quote the string `git reset "HEAD^"`, escape the character `git reset HEAD\^` or use a tilde if it's appropriate `git reset HEAD~1`

Comment: I don't see a problem with that since scripts can use `#!/usr/bin/env zsh -f` and I'm not sure that using `#!/usr/bin/env zsh` makes the script pick up configuration from `~/.zshrc`. If it does that could be a problem. And even then the script should set it's own options just to be sure. It should not be dependent on users specific configurations.

Comment: That's true, but I would still hesitate doing it on my system at least because it changes the expected behaviour of globbing patterns that could catch you out if you're not mindful. For example, `var=(*.fooext)` with `nomatch` unset will not produce an error if the glob match fails, it will instead create a string called "*.fooext" in the `var` array. And that might not be what you expect. Then again, these might just be edge cases, and I guess it's up to the user to decide for themselves the system they want...

Comment: `sh` and `ksh` don't default to abort on glob mismatch from the zsh docs, so I think most script tend to target `sh` compatibility maybe?

Answer (score 0):

On Mac escape the ^ in your command:

```
git reset --soft HEAD\^
```